# NavigationView можно ли изменить ширину

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Добрый день.
 Хочу чтобы выезжающая шторка была больше в ширину, чем в стандартном вызове.(не на весь экран, но оставшееся место, хотелось бы уменьшить раза в 2) Как это можно реализовать?

 Это текущая разметка

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/menus"
        style="@style/AppTheme"
        android:background="@drawable/mfon"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Когда я пытался сделать это окно шире, кроме как явно задавая размер я иначе не смог. Максимально 400dp кажется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, как через макет это сделать не нашел. Решил остановится на программном варианте. 
 Может кому и пригодится. Шторка заполняет 95% экрана

```
 nv=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
 int w=displaymetrics.widthPixels;
 DrawerLayout.LayoutParams lp = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) 
 nv.getLayoutParams();
 lp.width= (int) (w*0.95);
```

Answer (score 1):

За ширину отвечает атрибут **android:layout_width**. Установите его в требуемое значение. Например, чтобы сделать шторку шириной по содержимое

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

в вашей разметке это будет так

```
   <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/menus"
        style="@style/AppTheme"
        android:background="@drawable/mfon"
        />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Нет этот вариант не работает,  layout_width="match_parent" и android:layout_width="wrap_content" отрабатывают одинаково. 
Срабатывает только если выставить вручную, например  android:layout_width="500dp" 
Можно конечно инициализировать в коде, но хотелось бы это реализовать средством макета.

Comment: тогда можно попробовать поюзать **android:layout_marginRight** Используя даже отрицательные значения

Comment: Пробовал играть с параметрами реагирует только на положительные значения.

Comment: Установите например **android:layout_marginRight="-64dp"** у **android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout**

Comment: Если у DrawerLayout менять отступ, то все основное окно уползло в право, а шторка как открывалась примерно на 75% экрана так и открывается